# Discrepancy with screen orientation between Unity3d and iPad, game not affected by device rotation

Tags: c#, ipad, unity-game-engine, landscape, portrait

I'm helping develop a game in Unity3d using C#. We're developing for the iPad and using Unity's 
Apple plugin. Our game is a 2-D platform game that features gameplay that uses the rotation of the device (iPad). We're using physics for character movement.

The game is played mostly in Landscape Right. We can change the orientation of the device easy enough using `Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight`, etc. We want to be able to rotate the device from either `LandscapeLeft` and `LandscapeRight` to either `Portrait` or `PortraitUpsideDown`, which we can do.

When running our scene within Unity3d, when we rotate from Landscape to Portrait, our character falls because we rotate the world (what she's standing on), while she remains in the same orientation (physics remains the same), causing her to fall. This is the desired behavior we want. However, when we build to Xcode and run the game on the iPad simulator (version 5.1), and we rotate the device so that the world rotates, it merely rotates the device with the game still having the same orientation (landscape). The iPad is in portrait however the game is still in landscape. Are there other variables that we need to set within the device other that ScreenOrientation? How do we have our game state consistent with the device's orientation?

A quick summary: we want our game to default to Landscape. When we rotate to portrait we want the world to rotate with the camera and the player remaining constant. Physics is tied with the character meaning once the world rotates, she falls because she's no longer standing on the ground. Currently when we rotate the iPad, the orientation of the device changes but the game's orientation doesn't change. We want the world to shift on rotation but the character remain constant. It works in Unity3d but doesn't work correctly using the Xcode iPad simulator. How do we do this?

Thank you!

Kenneth

Comment: Is it an innate feature that Unity detects current orientation and automatically rotates the world? It sounds to me* like you're manually changing the scenario via a control in Unity, but haven't programmed a condition that actually checks for portrait orientation and adjusts accordingly. I would also test it on a real iPad if you can. *I have very limited experience with Unity.

Comment: Have you tested on an actual iPad?  iOS simulator is notoriously ill behaved.

Comment: It might help if you showed us some code, just in case it might be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Very confusing question, I must say. Checking the orientation should be simple and straight forward.

First and foremost: Forget XCode simulator! It sucks even if you're building directly on XCode and not using Unity or anything else. *Maybe* this alone already solves your issue. Get an iPad and test on it.

Also, you'll need *scripts* in place to *handle* the physics changing behavior with rotation. I couldn't understand if you got this, but in case you don't this might not be too trivial. Although it seems you got it.

Lastly, the most confusing part is when you talk about [`ScreenOrientation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.html) and [`Screen.Orientation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html), and just maybe there's a mistake there. When you use `Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight` you're forcing the actual screen orientation to change (it is not read-only) and this should be done only for testing purposes. You could even include all code relating to it inside `#if UNITY_EDITOR` and `#endif` precompiler 'tags'. For the device, you should only have `ScreenOrientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight`, either on `if` or `switch` clauses, with the comparison operator, the double equal sign (`==`).

Can't think of any other thing that could go wrong there.